# tmp file not uploaded PHP

Tags: php, apache, php-7.2

Since recently I am working with PHP and I came across a problem with uploading an image.

My code works well on my local machine; however, when uploaded on my VM the file is not getting uploaded to the tmp folder.

I have tried to see the array that is being filled from the **$_FILES** with "**print_r($_FILES);**" and this is what I get in the array:

```
array ( [image] => array ( [name] => avatar-1.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpfkhvrw [error] => 0 [size] => 1029 ) )
```

I have reviewed the **php.ini** file and everything seems to be in order. I have also checked a few other articles whit similar issues, but non of the suggestions worked.

I think that it is something to do with the permission as in the **envvars** file the configuration is the following:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

However, all of the files on the server are with root as user and group.

I really hope that someone can share some knowledge on this as I really don't know what to do next.

Comment: So are you saying that `/tmp/phpfkhvrw` does not actually exist?

Comment: Are you able to assign permission to the folder? I'd expect that www-data can probably already write to the folder, even if it doesn't own it. What are the current permissions on the folder?

Comment: Lets make it a little bit clearer: the file `/tmp/phpfkhvrw` does not exists or `move_uploaded_file('/tmp/phpfkhvrw', '/some/dest/folder/avatar-1.jpg')` returns `false`?

Answer (score 2):

What you have shown us here proves that the file upload was successful. You need to be a lot more specific as to what you think has failed.

As Zeusarm hints at, the file which has been created (/tmp/phpfkhvrw) does not persist after the HTTP request finishes - it is removed by PHP. If you want to retain this faile after the request then you need to call [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

> all of the files on the server are with root as user and group

You might want to work on your permissions model.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, What actually confused me is that the array says [error], and tough that this is causing the issue. It turns out that the file is simply not being moved, I had to change the owner and the group to "www-data:www-data" for the html dir and the tmp dir.

And the answer to my question was: "You might want to work on your permissions model."

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the file was being uploaded in the tmp dir but not being moved as the owner and group of the html and tmp folder was **root**.

Changed the owner and group of both of the folder and now everything works.

`sudo chown www-data:www-data FolderName -R`

Alternatively, permissions 777 can be used on all folders, but it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add chmod for your function. Example.

```
   // move_uploaded_file has is_uploaded_file() built-in
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $file_path)) {
                echo "File moved to: {$file_path}<br />";

                // remove execute file permissions from the file
                    if(chmod($file_path, 0644)) {
                        echo "Execute permissions removed from file.<br />";
                        $file_permissions = file_permissions($file_path);
                        echo "File permissions are now '{$file_permissions}'.<br />";
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: Execute permissions could not be removed.<br />";
                    }
            }
```